# Python-pptx: “Show legend overlapping the chart”

Tags: python, legend, python-pptx

I am using Office 2007. 
I found if I would like to show the legend overlapping the chart in office2007.
The XML should be as the following.

```
`-<c:legend>
   <c:overlay val="1"/>`
```

But no matter I use the API from python-pptx 'chart.legend.include_in_layout = True' or I leave it as the default. The generated XML would always be as the following.

```
`-<c:legend>
   <c:overlay/>`
```

Without the val=1, then office2007 won't show the format properly.
What can I do to force the python-pptx to write the val=1? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

In short, the `True` value is not explicitly set (in contrast to `False`) because `True` corresponds to the default value of `overlay`'s `val` attribute.

To explain it in more detail - you can follow the python-pptx hierarchy as follows: `overlay` is [mapped](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/pptx/oxml/__init__.py#L163) to [`CT_Boolean`](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/pptx/oxml/chart/shared.py#L20) (all overlay oxml elements are instantiated from CT_Boolean). The actual `val` parameter is then mapped via [`OptionalAttribute`](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/pptx/oxml/xmlchemy.py#L157) and is defined with the default value of `True`:

```
class CT_Boolean(BaseOxmlElement):
    """
    Common complex type used for elements having a True/False value.
    """
    val = OptionalAttribute('val', XsdBoolean, default=True)
```

Now, when setting the optional attribute to its default value, it is actually skipped/deleted, as you can see [here](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/pptx/oxml/xmlchemy.py#L201) `if value == self._default`:

```
class OptionalAttribute(BaseAttribute):
    """
    Defines an optional attribute on a custom element class. An optional
    attribute returns a default value when not present for reading. When
    assigned |None|, the attribute is removed.
    """

    @property
    def _setter(self):
        def set_attr_value(obj, value):
            if value == self._default:
                if self._clark_name in obj.attrib:
                    del obj.attrib[self._clark_name]
                return
            str_value = self._simple_type.to_xml(value)
            obj.set(self._clark_name, str_value)
        return set_attr_value
```

#### Fix - provide custom CT_Boolean class

Add these lines somewhere before you need to use the overlay. It will overwrite python-pptx `overlay` mapping with the custom `CT_Boolean_NoDefault` class:

```
from pptx.oxml import register_element_cls
from pptx.oxml.xmlchemy import BaseOxmlElement, OptionalAttribute
from pptx.oxml.simpletypes import XsdBoolean


class CT_Boolean_NoDefault(BaseOxmlElement):
    """
    Common complex type used for elements having a True/False value with no
    default value.
    """
    val = OptionalAttribute('val', XsdBoolean)

register_element_cls('c:overlay', CT_Boolean_NoDefault)
```

This worked for me and finally I got:

```
<c:legend>
    <c:overlay val="1"/>
</c:legend>
```

#### Fix - modify python-pptx permanently

This is not recommended but you might want to modify python-pptx instead of adding the solution from above for each script you run.

First, add the following to `pptx/oxml/chart/shared.py` which defines a new bool class without a default value:

```
class CT_Boolean_NoDefault(BaseOxmlElement):
    """
    Common complex type used for elements having a True/False value.
    """
    val = OptionalAttribute('val', XsdBoolean)
```

Second, modify `pptx/oxml/__init__.py` to add the new bool class:

```
from .chart.shared import (
    CT_Boolean, CT_Double, CT_Layout, CT_LayoutMode, CT_ManualLayout,
    CT_NumFmt, CT_Tx, CT_UnsignedInt, CT_Boolean_NoDefault
)
```

Third, modify `pptx/oxml/__init__.py` to change the mapping of the `overlay` element to the new bool class:

```
register_element_cls('c:overlay', CT_Boolean_NoDefault)
```

#### Better solution

In case you have time, please submit a ticket [`here`](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues) so it might become a permanent fix. In case [@scanny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902513/scanny) finds some time, he will read this. Perhaps there is some better solution for this, too, and I've completely missed something.

Comment: Excellent analysis pansen! :) This appears to be an unfortunate departure from the ISO/IEC spec in that version of PowerPoint. I like your solution to this because it localizes the compensation for Word's apparent non-conformance on this point; making the change to `CT_Boolean` itself has far-reaching effects because it's used so frequently. Specifying a default changes read behavior as well as write, such that `<c:overlay/>` would report `None` for legend.overlay vs. `True`. So the "fix" should be as localized as possible and even then may report wrong results for some versions on read.

Comment: ... but I'll put in a case for it and see about getting a compensating patch in there for the next release. Well done! :)

Comment: A compensating change that avoids this problem appears in v0.6.5, out today.

Comment: @scanny That's great. Thanks a lot for your work - python-pptx is a great package! Unfortunately, I haven't had time to take a closer look at ISO/IEC spec and how it relates to the current problem (I will come back to it later). As far as I understand, Powerpoint seems to have deviated from the spec whereas python-pptx correctly implemented the default value of the `overlay` element. Is this right so far?

Comment: Well, I would say python-pptx's implementation of CT_Boolean produces XML that is *permissible* according to the spec and consistent with the XML PowerPoint generates in many cases. We might call this style "implicit True". So e.g. `<c:overlay/>` is written for True and `<c:overlay val=0/>` is written for False. When reading, `<c:overlay/>` and `<c:overlay val=1/>` are both interpreted as True. This is a bit more compact, but requires reference to an external "default" value. Apparently Microsoft's code got the default wrong in this case. But it's not a bad idea for us to spell it out :)

Comment: The only part of the spec that applies here, as far as I can find, is the provided XML Schema. That clearly states that `true` is the default value for the `val` attribute, and PowerPoint commonly writes certain boolean elements without the val attribute. I'll probably move to always writing the `val` attribute going forward, just to be on the safe side :)

Answer (score 1):

@pansen 's analysis is spot-on. Here's an alternative way to get this working in your case that might be a little lighter weight:

```
def include_in_layout(legend):
    legend_element = legend._element
    overlay = legend_element.get_or_add_overlay()
    overlay.set('val', '1')
```

This appears to be a localized non-conformance of that version of PowerPoint with the ISO/IEC 29500 spec. As pansen rightly points out, a missing `val` attribute is to be interpreted the same as `val=1` (`True`). I'd be interested to discover how extensive this non-conformance goes, i.e. what other elements exhibit this same behavior. The `CT_Boolean` type is used quite frequently in PowerPoint, for things like bold, italic, varyColors, smooth, and on and on. So a "compensating" fix would need to be applied carefully to avoid reporting incorrect results for other elements.

I think I'll take pansen's cue and use a specialized element class for this element only. It will still report `True` for an element without the val attribute, which will be inconsistent with the observed behavior on this version of PowerPoint; but assuming other versions behave correctly (according to the spec), the inconsistency will be localized and at least assigning `True` to that property will make the legend show up the way you want.